# "Невообразимое разнообразие" - как однокоренные смотрятся в паре?

Tags: выбор-слов, тавтология

> И главное, выбирать будете вы сами из невообразимого разнообразия, а
>   не перебирать три-четыре услуги, на которых проще заработать
>   туристическому агенту.

И что-то в порядке слов меня смущает...

По просьбам трудящих - расширенный контекст:

> Лететь нужно в Найроби, остановиться в хорошем старинном английском
>   отеле (он такой единственный) – только там приличная консьерж-служба, то есть бесплатная служба,
>   которая занята исключительно тем, чтобы наиболее полно удовлетворить
>   ваши запросы. Если у вас нет такой финансовой возможности, тем не
>   менее рекомендую искать проводников на месте. Это будет значительно
>   дешевле! И главное, выбирать будете вы сами из невообразимого
>   разнообразия, а не перебирать три-четыре услуги, на
>   которых проще заработать туристическому агенту.

Comment: Похоже на скороговорку: перебирать невообразимое разнообразие. И не понятно, из разнообразия чего.

Comment: Ща дополню. Держися.

Comment: Порядок я бы поменяла:выбирать вы будете  сами. "Невообразимое разнообразие" - достаточно яркий образ, почти гипербола, по-моему, в данном  туристическом контексте смотрится нормально. Мне всё понятно: и про отель(он там один такой - старинный английский,  искать не придётся), и про финансовые возможности (не каждый может  себе позволить приличный отель), и про проводников - местные проводники и другие услуги оказывают -  и поселят, и местность покажут,и по магазинам проведут, и по музеям.

Comment: Люсенька, будьте ласка, пройдитесь по всем моим вопросам, заданным за последние дни, - тем, где Вы не отвечали и не комментировали. (Тут же много любителей-энтузиастов, а профессионалов раз два и обчёлся.)

Comment: @Людмила, Если понятно про отель, то хотя бы поменяте на "он там один такой". А непонятно к чему относящееся "тем не менее"?

Comment: Один на весь Найроби, тут всё в порядке. Тем не менее - да; понятно, о чём речь, но не вполне удачно. По смыслу: даже если вы стеснены в средствах, ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ (выброшу!) исхитритесь нанять проводника местного, а не отельного.

Comment: А не отельного? Так ведь местный дешевле! Не вижу логики. Вот если бы так: " даже если вы стеснены в средствах, тем не менее не оставайтесь совсем без усллуг, а найдите местного"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**невообразимый**
1.*книжн.* такой, который трудно представить себе, вообразить
*Блузки, юбки и платья отличались **невообразимым разнообразием.***
[Белое солнце пустыни](https://books.google.ee/books?id=6S5hAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT167&lpg=PT167&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC&source=bl&ots=rbeMBpznlt&sig=D_Qn_xArpUJ4Xd-HmemGrkHrFls&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1t5iI7pfTAhVIIJoKHTR1CsAQ6AEIOjAG#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC&f=false)

2.*перен.* необыкновенный, чрезвычайный, **исключительный** по силе проявления
*Жизнь — это последовательный сон, и когда он перестает сниться, весь мир с его красотой и болью, печалями, с его **невообразимым разнообразием** перестает существовать.*
[Уильям Сомерсет Моэм, Мудрые мысли](http://www.epwr.ru/quotauthor/293/txt17.php)

**разнообразие**
*• бесконечное разнообразие
• большое разнообразие
• великое разнообразие
• значительное разнообразие
**• исключительное разнообразие**
• наибольшее разнообразие
• невиданное разнообразие
• огромное разнообразие
• поразительное разнообразие
• редкое разнообразие*
(Словарь русской идиоматики. . Сочетания слов со значением высокой степени. Academic. 2011.)

А мне очень нравится это словосочетание:  *уж более в высокой степени* и не скажешь! И *никак* не вижу я их (слова) однокоренными.
Но в таком *обычно-повествовательно-рекламном*  тексте "***невообразимое*** разнообразие", мне кажется, просто не к месту. Можно подобрать что-нибудь попроще, не так *высоко*.

Comment: Как это "не вижу"*! О_о Корень - ОБРАЗ. Спасибо за ответ: Вы вторая, кому словосочетание не только не режет слух, но даже нравится. ))) И это не "обычно-повествовательно-рекламный" текст - живой рассказ!

Comment: Простите, но у "невообразимого" корень -ВООБРАЗ- . А Моэма куда денем? - это ведь известная цитата.

Comment: Мне тоже нравится, но если следом идет "перебирать" - то это уже перебор (каламбур случаино получился): обра-обра-перебира

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, а Моэм так и написал по-русски "с его невообразимым разнообразием" ?

Comment: Ну, совсем запинали! Я ведь только ПЫТАЛАСЬ высказать своё отношение. В ответе есть еще пример от Василия Ермакова. Он писал, надеюсь, не на английском.

Answer (score 1):

"Такой единственный" - звучит как восклицание, я бы поменял порядок слов. Непонятно, единственный хороший, стариный или английский.

"Такой финансовой возможности" так далеко отстоит от "лететь" и "остановиться", что непонятно,  о какой возможности речь.

"Тем не менее" - непонятна мысль. Несмотря на что?

Искать проводников на месте, выбирать из разнообразия, а не перебирать три-четыре услуги. Как будто выбирать из разнообразия проводников, проводники противопоставлены услугам (?)

По смыслу заметки, проводники - это люди, предоставляющие услуги, подобно турагентам. Мне такое значение слова "проводник" неизвестно.

Comment: Спасибо. Дело-то в Африке происходит, в Кении. Там действительно "проводники" по долинам и по взгорьям.